# ESM 401 Unauthorized error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, esm

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 server to Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm running the following commands to do so;

```bsh
apt update -y
apt upgrade -y
do-release-upgrade
```

`apt update` command runs fine with the following output;

```bsh
# apt update -y
Hit:1 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security InRelease
Hit:2 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

However when running the `apt upgrade` command, it returns the following errors;

```bsh
# apt upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done

*The following packages could receive security updates with UA Infra: ESM service enabled:
  libkrb5-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkrb5support0 libzstd1
Learn more about UA Infra: ESM service for Ubuntu 16.04 at https://ubuntu.com/16-04

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

The following packages have been kept back:
  libk5crypto3 libkrb5support0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libzstd1
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 esm-infra security update
Need to get 189 kB of archives.
After this operation, 132 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libzstd1 amd64 1.3.3+dfsg-2ubuntu1+esm1
  401  Unauthorized
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libz/libzstd/libzstd1_1.3.3+dfsg-2ubuntu1+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point. How can I solve this?

Comment: How long ago did you try? 401 can mean that a repo is down for whatever reason, it seems up now, alternatively you could try just removing `esm.ubuntu.com` form your sources list, since you are upgrading, you don't need extended support.

Comment: Well I tried a few minutes ago but I have multiple servers and I'm doing them all at the same time and while some of them works fine, some of them gives this error so I don't think the repo is down, I think it's related to my server.

Comment: @MarkKirby also I don't have `esm.ubuntu.com` in my sources list at all.

Comment: You say you're running 16.04 ESM, but those look like 18.04 ESM sources (they say `bionic` instead of `xenial`). 18.04 does not need to be ESM, since it's still in Community Support. This suggests that somebody already tried a `do-release-upgrade` that failed. Perhaps the upgrader left the altered sources in place (it happens). You can change the sources back to Xenial.

Comment: @user535733 Yes, I tried that myself but it failed. How can I revert this back?

Comment: The fact that it failed suggests that you might need to be prepared for a backup-and-reinstall. Depends upon the reason (check the logs!) Revert the sources change by simply substituting release names in /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two ways exist depending on currently running Ubuntu version.

### (a) Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as currently running version

You have to backup your `sources.list` by

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list ~/
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list ~/
```

and then fill main *`sources.list`* with correct URLs using one of commands below:

- plain *`sources.list`* replace

  ```
  cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main universe multiverse restricted
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe multiverse restricted
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe multiverse restricted
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main universe multiverse restricted
  EOF
  ```
- using `add-apt-repository`

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main universe multiverse restricted"
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe multiverse restricted"
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe multiverse restricted"
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main universe multiverse restricted"
  ```

and then resume upgrade to 18.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-advantage-tools --autoremove
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Then check `~/*.list` files from previous release and partially move the lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

### (b) Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as currently running version

You have to backup your `sources.list` by

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list ~/
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list ~/
```

and then fill main *`sources.list`* with correct URLs using one of commands below:

- plain *`sources.list`* replace

  ```
  cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main universe multiverse restricted
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe multiverse restricted
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main universe multiverse restricted
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main universe multiverse restricted
  EOF
  ```
- using `add-apt-repository`

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main universe multiverse restricted"
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe multiverse restricted"
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main universe multiverse restricted"
  sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main universe multiverse restricted"
  ```

and then install all necessary upgrades by:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-advantage-tools --autoremove
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then check `~/*.list` files from previous release and partially move the lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list` while replacing *xenial* with *bionic*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very detailed. For my case, only running the command `sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-advantage-tools --autoremove` alone solved my issue. I didn't have to do the other changes.

Comment: On an 18.04 system, the source of the problem was the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list` file. Commenting out the sources in there did the trick. I'm sure deleting it would have worked, too.

Answer (score 4):

On an 18.04 system (at least), look for a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list` file. That file erroneously lists sources for ESM updates that you would need to pay for, and `apt` is dutifully trying to download them.

I disabled those sources by putting a `#` before each of the two `deb` lines. The file now looks like this:

```
# Written by ubuntu-advantage-tools
#deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security main
# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security main

#deb https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-updates main
# deb-src https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates main
```

I think deleting the file would have worked, too.

Now, when I update the system again, using my usual update command:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt upgrade
```

...the `apt upgrade` portion doesn't try to download those unauthorized sources, and the upgrade is able to finish!

Answer (score 3):

When you register a system with Ubuntu Pro a `/etc/apt/auth.conf.d/90ubuntu-advantage` file is created. This file contains credentials tied to your Ubuntu account which gives that system permission to retrieve ESM updates.

I registered a system and initially it had no issues, but after some weeks attempts to retrieve packages from https://esm.ubuntu.com/ gave a HTTP 401 "Unauthorized" error.

I resolved the issue by detaching and reattaching the machine using the current Token value from https://ubuntu.com/pro/dashboard.

This regenerated the `/etc/apt/auth.conf.d/90ubuntu-advantage` file with current credentials.

1. sudo pro detach
2. sudo pro attach TOKEN_VALUE_HERE
3. sudo apt-get update

At this point I could apply updates (e.g., via `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude`) as before.