# Can't upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 18.04.6 LTS to next LTS (20.04?).  To do that, I first try to update everything about my current release (**sudo do-release-upgrade** seems to require that), but the **sudo apt upgrade** fails with a bunch of "401 Unauthorized [IP: blah.blah]" errors.  Yea, I know I should have upgraded a long time ago...
Any clue how to fix this?

System info...

```
$: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
$: uname -mrs
Linux 4.15.0-212-generic x86_64
$:
```

UPDATE:
Here is the output to update/upgrade:

```
$: sudo apt update

Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                            
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                            
Get:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security InRelease [7,530 B]                                                                                                        
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                                       
Get:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-updates InRelease [7,511 B]
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                               
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [83.3 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Fetched 276 kB in 1s (247 kB/s)                                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
51 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
$:
$:
$:sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  docker-scan-plugin gir1.2-snapd-1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following security updates require Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-infra' enabled:
  python2.7-dev libpython3.6-minimal libnghttp2-14 vim-common libx11-xcb-dev
  qemu-system-mips qemu-system-misc libpython3.6-dev qemu-system-ppc
  python3.6-venv python2.7-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib libpython2.7 python2.7
  qemu-system-x86 libpython3.6 python3.6 qemu-system-s390x libpython2.7-dev
  qemu-user libx11-6 libx11-6 python3-requests python3.6-minimal qemu libcap2
  libcap2 qemu-user-static qemu-utils libcap2-bin vim-runtime vim
  qemu-system-sparc xxd libx11-data libx11-dev libx11-doc libpython2.7-minimal
  vim-tiny qemu-system-arm python3.6-dev libpython2.7-stdlib qemu-block-extra
  qemu-system-common libx11-xcb1 libx11-xcb1 qemu-system
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docker-buildx-plugin ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon
The following packages will be upgraded:
  docker-ce-cli libcap2 libcap2:i386 libcap2-bin libnghttp2-14 libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3.6 libpython3.6-dev libpython3.6-minimal
  libpython3.6-stdlib libx11-6 libx11-6:i386 libx11-data libx11-dev libx11-doc libx11-xcb-dev libx11-xcb1 libx11-xcb1:i386 python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal python3-requests
  python3-software-properties python3.6 python3.6-dev python3.6-minimal python3.6-venv qemu qemu-block-extra qemu-system qemu-system-arm qemu-system-common qemu-system-mips
  qemu-system-misc qemu-system-ppc qemu-system-s390x qemu-system-sparc qemu-system-x86 qemu-user qemu-user-static qemu-utils software-properties-common software-properties-gtk vim
  vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny xxd
51 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
47 esm-infra security updates
Need to get 161 MB/200 MB of archives.
After this operation, 52.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:2 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:3 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:5 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-stdlib amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:8 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3.6-venv amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:9 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3.6-dev amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:10 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6-dev amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:11 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6 amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:12 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3.6 amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:13 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6-stdlib amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:14 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:15 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libpython3.6-minimal amd64 3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:16 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main i386 libcap2 i386 1:2.25-1.2ubuntu0.1~esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:17 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libcap2 amd64 1:2.25-1.2ubuntu0.1~esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:18 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-utils amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:19 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-system-common amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:20 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-block-extra amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:21 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libcap2-bin amd64 1:2.25-1.2ubuntu0.1~esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:22 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 vim amd64 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:23 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 vim-tiny amd64 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Ign:24 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1
Err:25 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 xxd amd64 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Ign:26 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 vim-common all 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1
Err:27 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libnghttp2-14 amd64 1.30.0-1ubuntu1+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Ign:28 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libx11-doc all 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1
Err:29 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libx11-dev amd64 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Ign:30 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libx11-data all 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1
Err:31 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libx11-6 amd64 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:32 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main i386 libx11-6 i386 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:33 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libx11-xcb-dev amd64 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:34 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main i386 libx11-xcb1 i386 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:35 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libx11-xcb1 amd64 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Ign:36 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3-requests all 2.18.4-2ubuntu0.1+esm1
Err:37 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-system-arm amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:38 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-system-mips amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:39 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-system-ppc amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:40 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-system-sparc amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:41 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-system-x86 amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:42 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-system-s390x amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:43 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-system-misc amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:44 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-system amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:45 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-user amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:46 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:47 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 qemu-user-static amd64 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:24 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:26 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 vim-common all 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:28 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libx11-doc all 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:30 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 libx11-data all 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
Err:36 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security/main amd64 python3-requests all 2.18.4-2ubuntu0.1+esm1
  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-dev_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.17-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6-venv_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6-dev_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-dev_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-stdlib_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/python3.6-minimal_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.6/libpython3.6-minimal_3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.13_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap2_2.25-1.2ubuntu0.1~esm1_i386.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap2_2.25-1.2ubuntu0.1~esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-utils_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-common_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-block-extra_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libc/libcap2/libcap2-bin_2.25-1.2ubuntu0.1~esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-tiny_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-runtime_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1_all.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/xxd_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vim/vim-common_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.13+esm1_all.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nghttp2/libnghttp2-14_1.30.0-1ubuntu1+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-doc_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1_all.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-dev_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-data_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1_all.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-6_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-6_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1_i386.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-xcb-dev_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-xcb1_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1_i386.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libx11/libx11-xcb1_1.6.4-3ubuntu0.4+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/r/requests/python3-requests_2.18.4-2ubuntu0.1+esm1_all.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-arm_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-mips_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-ppc_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-sparc_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-x86_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-s390x_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system-misc_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-system_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-user_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu-user-static_2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.42+esm1_amd64.deb  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2001:67c:1562::21 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
$:
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: @Esther: Tried changes based on 91815, but got a few similar errors with sudo apt update.  Example... 
 Err:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::1a 80]

Comment: apparently recent(ish) *LTS* versions are archived at `archive.ubuntu.com` rather than `old-releases.ubuntu.com`. Change all `old-releases` to `archive` and it should work properly. Maybe I'll add an answer to that question because I think it's canonical

Comment: @Esther: That's what is currently in my /etc/apt/sources.list. I tried changing to "old-releases.ubuntu.com", and then also saw some folks said use "us.archive.ubuntu.com".  Both had similar problems.

Comment: hmm looks like the esm archives are the problem, since you (presumably) didn't pay for ESM but you have them listed as sources. See [this q&a](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371293/esm-401-unauthorized-error-on-ubuntu-16-04) for how to deal with that

Comment: @Esther well it took a while, but that seems to have done it!  I'm now running 20.04.6 LTS.  Thanks very much for your help!