# Why does the "Files" window (nautilus) crash on 20.04.6 LTS?

Tags: nautilus

I installed 20.04.6 LTS recently and just clicked on the "Files" icon to open a file and it immediately closed.  Tried several times, rebooted, no change.  Tried running nautilus from  a terminal window and same thing happens, but I see the message:

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: 07:31:23.797: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Generally, a segfault is a bug, and it needs to be reported to the developers, we can't help you with it. Having said that, does it help to restart `nautilus`? Try `nautilus -q && nautilus`.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck... Doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Then please create an account and file an issue here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues

Comment: Yuk... not having luck with that now either.  When creating an issue it asks that you make sure the bug wasn't fixed in a nightly build, and use "flatpak" to get that build.  I get an error when attempting to install flatpak...The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.28.4+git20200505-0ubuntu18.04.2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: Thanks. I would give up, at that point.

Comment: Wise advice.  :-)

Comment: Well, for what its worth (for anyone else that may run into this)... Apparently "mutter" is some other X-window manager.  I installed it, and now the "Files" button works, but brings up a different UI (doesn't matter to me, I just want something to work).

Comment: I would have thought Gnome 3.36 (including Mutter) was the default on 20.04LTS.

Comment: Unless something got screwed up when I upgraded from 18.04...I did have to jump through hoops to get through that upgrade... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1473872/cant-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04